# Contacts list in kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, contacts, addressbook

I'm writing an app for android, and need some help. My question is how can I display the list of contacts (address book in other words) that I have stored on my phone, sim card, and google, in the kivy app, so I can select one of them and get the number inside my kivy app? I don't care if it's an external menu from android or google for example, what I need is just a way to select a contact from the app, and then save the number inside a variable.
Is there a way to do that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have two options: either use pyjnius to call the java android api to retrieve the contacts, or use pyjnius to open an external app and return the result via android's message passing (presumably intents).

Comment: @inclement Can you provide an example of the first option, please?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't have an example. I would proceed by reading the pyjnius docs, other pyjnius example code and android api documentation.